# Comma in a two-item list?

Tags: commas

How would you punctuate list of two items that has the word AND in the title?

For example:

> ... two documents with titles of Power of Attorney and Living Will and Appointment of Health Care Agent.

Comment: Obniously, you put one comma between the titles to disambiguate. A and B, and C // A, and B and C.

Comment: Don't overthink it. Commas can basically be seen as "a pause should go here." How would you say it? Put the comma where the pause is.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to use a comma after the first title, and even if you are writing to a style guide that normally forbids it, then unless it specifically addresses this case a good point could be made for making an exception.

Either way, it would be more important to signify what is or isn't part of the title with italics or quotes depending on the type of documents:

> *Power of Attorney and Living Will*, and *Appointment of Health Care Agent*
>
> "Power of Attorney and Living Will", and "Appointment of Health Care Agent"

Comment: I'd be inclined to use quotation marks but not a comma. I might use a comma to reflect a pause in reported speech, although I guess I'd just assume that the pause reflects the “unquoting” between the titles.

Comment: @BraddSzonye yeah, perfectly fine too, though choosing between quotation marks and italics also depends on the type of documents, with overlapping styles existing on that point too.