# Do I need a semicolon to separate two items with internal commas in a numbered run-in list sentence?

Tags: punctuation, complex-sentences

I asked this Q in ELL, but I found related Qs here.

Here is a numbered run-in list sentence.

> **(A)** The UI program provides temporary income support to **(1)** eligible unemployed workers while they actively seek new employment or obtain vocational training **;** **and** to **(2)** those who take time off from work due to sickness, pregnancy, childbirth, or to provide care to a critically ill child or a sick family member with a significant risk of death.

Without the numbers, it would read:

> **(B)** The UI program provides temporary income support to eligible unemployed workers while they actively seek new employment or obtain vocational training **and** to those who take time off from work due to sickness, pregnancy, childbirth, or to provide care to a critically ill child or a sick family member with a significant risk of death.

Here is my problem.

(1) Usually, in a two word/phrase list a comma is not used before "and". Also, my sentences are not both independent clauses, hence the conjunction should not have a comma before it.

(2) In a run-in list, if there is internal commas, then the items should be separated by semicolons. My clause (2) has internal commas.

Now, these two guidelines conflict in my case. All examples in the [Chicago MS](https://www-chicagomanualofstyle-org.ezproxy.library.uvic.ca/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec129.html) contain 3 items or more.

I have seen all these Qs asked here before. [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481664/comma-or-no-in-a-two-item-list-where-those-items-are-phrases), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391842/using-a-comma-in-a-list-of-two-when-the-first-item-is-very-long), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151359/comma-in-a-two-item-list?rq=1). What I gathered from them is that in a special case when a two item sentence is complex, there can be a comma before the conjunction. But I am still confused as to what it should be when it is a numbered list.

My questions is, in the case where there are two items (and those items have internal commas) is it still the rule to put in a semicolon before "and"?

Comment: Can someone tell me why this got a downvote? I did provide links to the research I did before posting here. My question is clear, and I provided enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, 'Guidelines' are just that: guidelines; they are not rules that must be followed. Does the additional punctuation make it easier and/or clearer for the reader? Does it save the reader having to do a 'double think' and/or having to go back and re-read the sentence? Unless you are writing for a publisher who has strict rules about such issues, then do what seems appropriate and what you think would be clearest for your readers.

Personally, I would put a semicolon after *"training"* in **both** forms of your sentence.  In fact, I would go so far as to say that it is more important in format **B** than in format **A**, because format **A** already has the numbering that clearly separates the two groups, whereas **B** does not have that extra 'break'.

For similar reasons, I would argue that the use of a semicolon (as opposed to a comma) is more important in **B** than in **A**, because again the numbering in **A** makes the division of the two groups clear.  On the other hand, **B** already uses commas *within* the second section, so it needs a *stronger* indicator than a comma (*i.e.* a semicolon) to separate the two *main* groupings.

Clarity to your readers is more important than arbitrary rules!

P.S. I'm writing this as a Brit, not an American, so the opinions on your side of 'the pond' may be different!

Comment: You explained it really well. If, for the purposes of clarity and readability of my reader (and myself), I do include the semicolon, which do you think is more appropriate--A or B?

Comment: In my personal view, A is the clearer because the numbers make the two options very clear.